# Looking for a better way to remove white space for IE6

Tags: css, xhtml, html-lists, removing-whitespace

currently when I code a list I do this:

```
<ul><!--
   --><li><a href="" title="">something</a></li><!--
   --><li><a href="" title="">something</a></li><!--
   --><li><a href="" title="">something</a></li><!--
   --><li><a href="" title="">something</a></li><!--
   --><li><a href="" title="">something</a></li><!--
   --><li><a href="" title="">something</a></li><!--
   --><li><a href="" title="">something</a></li><!--
--></ul>

    <ul><!--
    --><li><a title="" href="">something</a><!----></ul>
```

but on much larger websites with much much more complicated navigation menu's this isnt practical and the code looks scattered etc..... does anyone know of a way to get rid of the white space and keep clean looking code.. I thought I might ask just encase... this bothers me every site..

sorry for a bad example its hard to format properly here..

Thanks for your replies, this was a general interest type post...
Im gonna try Ahsan Rathod's and DanialB's replies....

Im affraid our clients still use this browser (IE6) so we have to use this dusty ol'browser.

next time ill post css, this time I didnt this it was worth it as I assumed everyone probly coded for IE6 at somepoint and came across this...

Thanks again for all your replies though..

Comment: Why do you use `<!--
   -->` ? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What's your problem with whitespaces? I can't think of the reason you would want to get rid of them

Comment: You'd get a better answer if you included your CSS. You should also create a [JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/) showing the problem. Are you sure the problem *only happens* with IE6?

Comment: ok, will add css etc next time, I just assumed this was a normal practice a common problem, we use this method at work a lot.. Im talking about the IE6 white space bug..

Comment: IE6 has an awful lot of bugs. I'm not going to sit here and *guess* which one you're talking about.. If you make a [JS Bin demo](http://jsbin.com/) showing the problem, I will properly answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White spaces would only be rendered in lists, if you style the list items as `inline` elements. You could use floating blocks instead and no white spaces will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried :

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this approach, though it's also not ideal.

```
<ul
  ><li>Foo</li
  ><li>Bar</li
  ><li>Baz</li
  ><li>Quux</li
></ul>
```

One thing to consider, IE6 is ancient now, and even Microsoft are ready to pull the plug on it.  Is making accommodations for a 10 year old browser with 3 successive versions really worth it?

Comment: haha, I wish it was my choice - when I freelance I send IE6 users to a holding page explaining how to update the browser! I hae IE... but weather I like it or not our clients use this browser therefore we have to code for them..